# Maven build failure: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body

Tags: eclipse, maven

When doing `mvn clean install` on the package, many projects build but some failed. This was because those were big external `jar`s (like snappy and jline). The error message was as below:

> failed to execute goal on project list-GR-wrapper: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxx.services.list:list-GR-wrapper:pom:1.60.0.18-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: jline:jline:jar:0.9.94, org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact jline:jline:jar:0.9.94 from/to nexus (http://gec-maven-nexus.companyname.com/nexus/content/groups/public): GET request of: jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar from nexus failed: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 87325; received: 52223 -> [Help 1]

Answer (score -5):

The solution was simple.

1. added the setting file in `<mvn>/conf/` folder.
2. in Eclipse, *Preferences* → *Maven* → *User settings*, point to this `settings.xml` created at step 1.

and you are done.